# Extraer día de fechas de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
[
"2022-01-03",
"2022-01-04",
"2022-01-05",
"2022-01-06",
"2022-01-07",
"2022-01-08",
"2022-01-10",
"2022-01-11",
"2022-01-12",
"2022-01-13",
"2022-01-14",
"2022-01-15",
"2022-01-17",
"2022-01-18",
"2022-01-19",
"2022-01-20",
"2022-01-21",
"2022-01-22",
"2022-01-24",
"2022-01-25",
"2022-01-26",
"2022-01-27"]
```

Como hago para extraer solo el dia? Mi fecha está en este formato: YYY-MM-DD y necesito extraer solo los días y guardalos en otro array

Comment: ¿Por que necesitas extraer los dias? No es mejor leer directamente el array con los dias, en vez de crear uno nuevo con solo los dias ?

Comment: Para poder pintar solo los días en un gráfico. Si lo mando así me pinta año mes y días. Alguna otra forma de hacer que pinte solo los días? Solo se me ocurrió extraer los días en un array aparte y eso mandarlos al grafico

Comment: Extrae solo los dias, y regresas solo los dias

Comment: Y como hago eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear un objeto de tipo fecha a partir de la cadena, y con eso puedes obtener el día.

```
const dates = [
"2022-01-03",
"2022-01-04",
"2022-01-05",
"2022-01-06",
"2022-01-07",
"2022-01-08",
"2022-01-10",
"2022-01-11",
"2022-01-12",
"2022-01-13",
"2022-01-14",
"2022-01-15",
"2022-01-17",
"2022-01-18",
"2022-01-19",
"2022-01-20",
"2022-01-21",
"2022-01-22",
"2022-01-24",
"2022-01-25",
"2022-01-26",
"2022-01-27"];

const days = dates.map( d => new Date( d ).getDate() );
console.log( days );
```

Una forma no propia de hacerlo es partir en pedacitos la fecha y regresar los últimos 2 dígitos

```
const pieces = dates.map( d => d.split('-')[2] );
console.log( pieces );
```

Answer (score 2):

Si es javascript puro puedes usar el siguiente código:

```js
  const array1 = [
    "2022-01-03",
    "2022-01-04",
    "2022-01-05",
    "2022-01-06",
    "2022-01-07",
    "2022-01-08",
    "2022-01-10",
    "2022-01-11",
    "2022-01-12",
    "2022-01-13",
    "2022-01-14",
    "2022-01-15",
    "2022-01-17",
    "2022-01-18",
    "2022-01-19",
    "2022-01-20",
    "2022-01-21",
    "2022-01-22",
    "2022-01-24",
    "2022-01-25",
    "2022-01-26",
    "2022-01-27"]

  const array2 = [];

  array1.forEach(element => {
    array2.push(element.substr(8,2));
  });
  
  console.log(array2);
```

También tienes otras otras alternativas como Jquery en combinacion con underscore.js

Espero haber sido de ayuda.
Saludos

Comment: Puedes explicar cómo funciona este código? No es solo para mí, es para todos los que busquen el mismo resultado

Comment: La idea es recorrer el arreglo (forEach) y cortar el texto (substr) para devolver los dos últimos caracteres.